# Can imported Alembic be set to collision and affect cloth?

Tags: physics, alembic

I thought I could just import an abc file, set it to collision and have its movement affect my Cloth-Ball on collision.

Just, it does not collide. Just goes through the cloth.

Comment: try using ctrl+A. apply scale , rotation and location and then check.

Comment: No, does not work. It is a fluid that I exported as abc and import it again. If I bake it to an animation it creates an NLA strip. But either way this fluid mesh (it is not a fluid anymore) does not collide with my cloth or any other rigid or soft bodies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Alembic files.

I have found that if I add a "Weld" modifier first (or Remesh), then they can participate in physics. Maybe this was the same issue with your files.